# SQL multiple tables join and pivot with column name and value

Tags: sql, pivot

I'm looking for a way to join  two (sometimes more) tables.
I'll start with two and add as I get the pieces working.

Table1 has two columns that identify it

```
T1ContainerID
T1ObjectID
```

Table2 has similar columns but starts with T2 but the values will match

```
T2ContainerID
T2ObjectID
```

In Table2 there are two columns I am targeting

```
ObjectName
ObjectValue
```

There can be any number of ObjectName entries for a given record.
For instance one may have name, address,and a date
another may have Name, address,port,date,ServerName,Device,Status

What I need is a way to pivot all of the potential columns in Table2 in line with Table1 and is that value is not in Table2 for table1 then just make it NULL. I want the header of these columns to be the ObjectName and the value to be ObjectValue. If i can't get a wildcard to grab all potential values i can settle for just calling out each column manually. I was only hoping for a wildcard as it may change as different values for new records get added. Worst case i just adjust code to add anything new.

I do have a bunch of queries that rebuild the database every night and dump it into a different database but I'd like to have a query to pull the results from the main database to get current values rather than something that was run every morning.

Comment: please write a sample input and expected output

Comment: You want dynamic pivoting - this is product specific. Tag yours dbms.

Comment: I can't paste my example it tells me it is too long. :(
And it's not passing along the formatting.